# Condensing an adjacency matrix for shortest tour

Tags: java, algorithm, traveling-salesman, adjacency-matrix

I have a program that reads a data file and inputs the data as a 16 x 16 adjacency matrix. I need to find 10 nodes of the graph out of the 16 for which there is a minimal tour. Could someone show me how to implement a traveling salesperson algorithm that accomplishes this? I know how to do it for all 16 nodes, but I don't know how to condense it to only 10.

```js
public class Tour 
{
 public static final int N = 16;
 public static final int INF = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 
 public static void printGrid(int[][] adjMat)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
       {
          for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
          {
          if(adjMat[i][j] == INF)
           System.out.printf("%5s", 0);
          else
           System.out.printf("%5d", adjMat[i][j]);
          }
          System.out.println();
       }
    }
 
 public static void TSP(int[][] adjMat)
 {
  adjMat = new int[N][N];
  
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
 {

     File file = new File("american_tour.dat");

     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

     scanner.useDelimiter("[\\s,]+");

     int N = scanner.nextInt();
     int[][] adjMat = new int[N][N];

     for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
         for (int j=0; j < N; j++) 
              adjMat[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();

     printGrid(adjMat);
     scanner.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean finding which of the 10 nodes to visit in a TSP problem where the overall travel will be the least (i.e. isolating the other 6 that would contribute larger distances?)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: It's been a few years since I've worked on things like this but would a MST comparison of each possible 10-length subset not suffice?